# View .NET Core projects on real mobile device on mac

Tags: macos, .net-core, rider

I am using IntelliJ Rider for developing .NET Core apps on mac.
How can I view my app, which is hosted on localhost, on my mobile device in same sub network?

Comment: This question was already asked on stackoverflow on the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005540/localhost-running-on-mac-can-i-view-it-on-my-android-phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Localhost running on mac.. Can I view it on my Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005540/localhost-running-on-mac-can-i-view-it-on-my-android-phone)