# How to test PWA on over HTTPS with self-signed OpenSSL certificate?

Tags: android, openssl, progressive-web-apps, self-signed

I am able to test serviceworkers over http with localhost but I would like to testg on a mobile browser.  Because it is a separate device I cannot use localhost so I use the name of the PC. So now I need to use https, which is causing SSL related errors in my service worker:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://xxx:5500/app/') with script ('https://xxx:5500/app/service_worker.js'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script.

I have properly configured liveServer to use self-signed certs and I've successfully enabled "edge://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure" but it is not enough.

I'm also concerned about how to test PWA on the mobile device as I presume I cannot make use of the "unsafely" feature on mobile.  I assume this is a common scenario but I am not finding any answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can test your PWA on mobile via chrome developer tools:
the method called remote debugging (works only for android)

1. open developer tools in mobile - allow usb debugging
2. connect via usb to laptop or pc
3. go to chrome dev tools open remote devices
4. set port forwarding in remote device
5. run local host in mobile chrome browser.

for detailed info follow : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

this provides localhost in a mobile devices so no need for https or ssl.

I think this is the best way to test your PWA, I have personally used it.

Comment: Confirming you can hit "localhost" from mobile device with proper setup.  Do not use https with an invalid/self-signed certificate or the device will fail to run the service worker.

Answer (score 4):

Another working solution than is to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which will create a live https-server for the project you want (and then you'll be able to access it on your mobile device)

Comment: This is a fantastic solution.  You run ngrok http 5000 and it forward port 5000 so that you can access localhost:5000 via some random ngrok url, such as  https://9a49b431.ngrok.io -> http://localhost:5500.  I think the free version continually changes the endpoint.  It may be https://3cb5f24e.ngrok.io the next time I run ngrok.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to install `Termux` on your Android phone, then use `socat` to port-forward from a local port to your development host:

```
socat tcp-l:8000,fork,reuseaddr tcp:192.168.1.170:8000
```

This will run in the background while the terminal is open. Then in Chrome you can connect over plain HTTP to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` and you should get the "Add x to Home screen" notice.

Works great over the local network and no certs, apps or services needed.