# FCM Push Notification logic in react chat pwa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a react chat PWA. I want to use FCM for push notification. As we see on WhatsApp and Messenger, user only receives new message notification when he/she is away.

So, I want to show notification when the opposite user sends message. But I'm not able to do that logic. Can you please help me by suggesting what to do? Or, can you share a code snippet for the PWA push notif?

By the way, the back-end API is set in Laravel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out these articles for reference -

1. [PWA series with FCM](https://dev.to/thisdotmedia/intro-to-pwa-and-service-workers-15d4)
2. [Implementing Push notification with FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)
3. [Official Google Docs](https://www.codemag.com/article/1901031/Implementing-Push-Notifications-in-Progressive-Web-Apps-PWAs-Using-Firebase)

I hope it will help developing the push notification feature

The basic steps involved are -

1. Set up firebase app on google developer console
2. Add the keys on your React app (follow the official doc)
3. Add service worker for push notification
4. This service worker will have all the logic you would like to have like when to receive notification like on-screen or off-screen
5. Test the feature on mobile (reference - [How to test PWA on mobile with local server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60500370/12333430))