# Calling web service from Android app seems to hang

Tags: java, android, web-services, asmx, ksoap2

I am trying to call an asmx web service from an Android app. Just literally started some Android development today. I've been following various solutions I have found on the net and on here and it seems it is more difficult than anticipated. I have tried various solutions and using KSoap2 seems to be the easiest way to implement this, well it would be if I could get it working.

I have the following code which works up until a point:

```
private class CallWebService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetUser";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetUser";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://160.10.1.79:59315/Service1.asmx";
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

        try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

            tv.setText(result.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

It seems to hang at the line `androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);` Any ideas why? Is this the correct approach? Should I be looking in another direction?

Comment: what do you mean it hangs? it hang there for a few seconds or indefinitely?

Comment: It hangs indefinitely. Doesn't throw a timeout exception, or any exception for that matter. I just have to stop it running manually. I'm going to try a more recent version of KSoap2 to see if that makes any difference. I think the version I'm using dates from 2006!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the solution for this was quite simple in the end. The web service was running under localhost, but would not work using `localhost:59315`. So I changed it to `**MY IP**:59315`. Still didn't work. Using this question [Accessing localhost:port from Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator) I tried using `10.0.2.2:59315` and it worked. So thanks go to Akhil Jain in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

```
 tv.setText(result.toString());
```

It is not at all recommended to access UI from `doInBackground`.

`doInBackground` will automatically pass result to `onPostExecute` and you can set the text there

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
   tv.setText(result.toString());
}
```

Comment: This is not an issue really, it is a test app and only being tested for functionality purposes. "Not recommended" I understand, but this has nothing to do with my issue as this line doesn't even get hit!