# android dictionary how to fetch from xampp database

Tags: android, database, xampp, fetch

i am trying to develop dictionary for my project with xampp as my database. I want to fetch the definition of words in my database to android. Please help how to do this.

Comment: Use Web-service to communicate with online database and after read web service store it in android database.

Comment: i have to use  localhost only that's why i'm using xampp. DO i have to create table in database for all definitions and fetch it to android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator

Comment: yes a localhost. i know how to connect my android to my database. I just want to know how to do this dictionary. A list of words and when i click the word i will fetch the meaning from the database. It will display the meaning of the word i clicked. I hope u get what i mean.

Comment: i tried making table ex. diction with name and definition as its column. i inserted values to it and fetch it using php. ex. show.php and put the url to the to java in android and when user click that word it will fetch the meaning. but the problem is i will have to create for php files to display each meaning. How can i do it in only one or two php files.

Comment: This actually the problem, I have to call another intent and that intent or new class has to load a url that contains .php. A problem of creating more classes for every meaning of the word to display. please help me fix this problem.