# my android application is not geting json data from the server

Tags: php, android, json

**here is the code but it can not get the json data although the browser is showing the json data when i m turning it on why?the php code is working fine but when the android is trying to fetch it says i am fetching null**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    StrictMode.enableDefaults();
    resultview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.resulttext);
    getdata();

}

public void getdata()
{
    String result=null;
    InputStream inputstream=null;
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/getallcustomers.php");
        HttpResponse response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpentity=response.getEntity();
        inputstream= httpentity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resultview.setText(ex.getMessage()+"at 1st exception");
    }
    try{
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        String line=null;
        while((line=reader.readLine())!= null)                  
        {
            sb.append(line +"\n");
        }
        inputstream.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        resultview.setText(ex.getMessage()+"at 2nd exception");
    }
    try{
        String s="test :";
        JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0; i<jarray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            s= s +
                    "Name : "+json.getString("firstname")+" "+json.getString("lastname")+"\n"+
                    "age :"+json.getString("age")+"\n"+
                    "phone : "+json.getString("phone");
        }
        resultview.setText(s);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        this.resultview.setText(ex.getMessage()+"at 3rd exception");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: <?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','admin','666666');
if (!$con) {
 die('could not connect:'. mysql_error()); 
}
mysql_select_db('customer',$con);

$result=mysql_query("select * from customer");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 # code...
 $output[]=$row;
}
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>  here is php

Comment: What results do you see when you access your php file directly?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can access your localhost from the emulator? You should take a look at this:
[Accessing localhost:port from Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator)

Comment: mann thanks a lot i didnt know that, it works now after inserting 10.0.2.2:80 as the ip thanks again man. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are launching the http request on UI thread. Probably it crashes for this.

Try to log the exception, not put in your resultview object and confirm that

Comment: it works now everything is allright i had to use the correct ip with the correct port for android.

Answer (score 0):

is your php version 5.5?

you should use mysqli not use mysql

the php code is correct, perhaps the access database does not have the correct data

Answer (score 0):

Code to get json data from server. It is working fine for me.

```
private void get_valueFromServer(String php) {
String responseString = null;
try{    
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url ="your_url"; 
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
    out.close();
    responseString = out.toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),responseString,1000).show();

    //The below code is for Separating values.It may varies according with your result from server.

    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(responseString);
    int x=Integer.parseInt(ja.getJSONObject(0).getString("your_string_name"));

} catch(Exception e) {
}
}
```