# Android Application Network Error failed to connect

Tags: android

I'm using the following coding to connect locally on my `SQL` database

```
String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/dbname";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,"user","pass");
```

When I'm running this application it gives me `Network error`. Failed to connect to `127.0...`

My firewall is open for `1433` and `SQL` config `TCP/IP` is enabled. What else must I still do?

Comment: Have you given INTERNET permission ?

Comment: I did add Internet permission

Comment: For future reference: This thread explains it pretty well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this error. I was working on jtds driver v1.3.1. When I'm using the older version it works. I'm using now v1.2.5

Answer (score 6):

If you are referring to a `localhost` from your device than use the `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` instead of the `http://127.0.0.1/` or `http://localhost/`.

Because your Android emulator is running on a `Virtual Machine(QEMU)` and you can not connect to a server directly running on your PC.

And If you running your app from Physical android device then please use your network ip from your PC.
for example  `http://198.10.12.21:80/`....

Also make sure that your device and PC(from where you call localhost) within same Network

Comment: I did test all the IP but still give me the same error. When I'm using the PC IP the application just quit. When I'm using the wrong IP it will tell me it is the wrong IP but the correct IP the application just stop

Comment: I'm using the default 1433 port and it is on the same network

Comment: @BlackTiger Both of addresses doesn't work for me! 10.0.2.2:8080 for emulator, 192.168.1.3 for physical device, even 10.0.2.2:80. And i don't get any response or error in Log.