# Android device connection with localhost server

Tags: android, mysql, ip

I am new at android. I am devloping an app that uses MySQL. The application runs well in the emulator. But now I need to run the app in a android device. What can I do.

Comment: post your manifest file here?? and Also Check Internet permission.

Comment: You need to set your network's ip instead 
See my answer 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234768/android-application-network-error-failed-to-connect/21234855#21234855

Comment: <!--  Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Thy this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032554/12298875

Comment: If you're still facing the issue, feel free to give this a try : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032554/12298875

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the first comment, you should check your file AndroidManifest.xml.

In order to access the network, it should contain the following instructions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You may also add the following, which enable your application to know the actual state of the network connection.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: "The application runs well in the emulator" means permission are already written in Manifest file.

Comment: Ok, fine ; but was it really necessary to push the -1 button ? I did not know that trying to honestly help the submitter was a wrong action...though my answer did not bring more light to the topic.