# HttpGet on localhost connect failed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a android application that gets data from a REST service as JSON.

I am using a PC , windows, eclipse and a android emulator.

In this function here below. If I use a URL that is live on the internet then it works perfectly.

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese.php?puzzle=1");
```

but if I use a url that is hosted locally ( using visual studio ) on my own pc I get  a error saying **"Conection refused."**

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://" + "localhost:50851/Default.aspx");

How do I connect to my local host?  Thnaks

---

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
             HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
             //HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese.php?puzzle=1");
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://" + "localhost:50851/Default.aspx");
             //
             String text = null;
             try {
                   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                   text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 return e.getLocalizedMessage();
             }
             return text;
        }
```

Comment: Refer this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234768/android-application-network-error-failed-to-connect/21234855#21234855`

Comment: use 10.0.0.2 instead of localhost.

Comment: Because your Android emulator is running on a Virtual Machine(QEMU) and you can not connect to a server directly running on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

In your computer, open command line, enter **ipconfig** in windows(linux ifconfig) you can see your IP address.

```
Example: 192.168.0.111

Change **localhost** by **192.168.0.111**
```

Localhost just in computer, It is not in your mobile

Answer (score 0):

use 10.0.0.2 as localhost,

refer to here : [Refer this one](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use localhost when running on Device/Emulator.
In this case request will be forwarded to the devices's loopback interface.
Just change localhost with ip of you PC

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://" + "your.computer.ip:50851/Default.aspx");
```