# How can I connect in emulator to the local host

Tags: android

I have `wamp server` in my windows. Also  I have an android program that it should connect to my database and my `php` files.I created my database in `wamp server` and I saved my `php` files in `www` folder.

Also I have an image in `http://127.0.0.1/index/image.jpg` folder in the `wamp server` and also I use `http://127.0.0.1/index/image.jpg` in source code.But when I run my program in emulator, It can not load the image from `wamp server` folder.

I am pretty sure my code is correct.What is the solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

To access your localhost server you'll have to use the special  `10.0.2.2` ip. You could also use the real ip of your machine on which the emulator is running on.

More at http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 1):

You are connecting Android emulator to your localhost, you use 10.0.2.2 for connecting to localhost server.

as android emulator is acting as a device it has it own loopback interface which is 127.0.0.1 therefore it is inside android emulator. and it has its own ip address 10.0.2.15. now that mean you need to connect to server running in your development machine from android emulator.

reference
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to connect device to your pc through wi-fi - they should be in the same network, so ping command on device should return a value. Next you need to open port on your PC, just add a rule for your server in your firewall.