# Access Localhost IIS from Android VM

Tags: android, iis, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

My ASP website is running by way of the default IIS server included in Visual Studio 2015. This is accessed by the URL localhost:50544. I have to use 'Genymotion' to run an android virtual machine. Geny motion uses virtualbox so if need be I can edit the virtual machines configuration directly via virtualbox.

I'd like to visit my website from the android browser.

I've edited the android virtual machine to include a second bridged adapter and attempted to visit 10.0.2.2:50544 from within the android VM. It does not load and eventually the browser will produce a time out error. Someone's similar question [mentions visiting 10.0.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator) when specifically using genymotion. But this has the same outcome.

How may I visit the website from within the android virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using your local IP address?

Like my IP would be: 192.169.2.9

Comment: I got the address via CMD ipconfig and it is 192.168.1.13. Visiting it on port 50544 produces the same time out error

Comment: Hmm. You did copy the IP address of the virtualbox vnet? PS: Why do you need to use Android?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have done this correctly but there's "Virtualbox Host-Only Network" entry and it's address is 192.168.56.1. Using that still gives the time out.

Comment: And you do use the address: 192.168.56.1:50544 ?

Comment: Yes I've tried visiting it on the android virtual machine's web browser but it still fails to load the website

Comment: Uhm, did you try `10.0.2.2:50544` ? It was stated on another question