# Android emulator not working with local server

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I am using with localhost the data is displaying in a web browser but it's not working with an emulator.

http://localhost:51411/api/MobileAPI/Authenticate?UID=abc&PWD=123&DeviceId=94944c77-931c-4cd3-aa23-889b9d8963f7

When I am using with android emulator is not working with this IP 10.0.2.2 not displaying the data

http://10.0.2.2:51411/api/MobileAPI/Authenticate?UID=abc&PWD=123&DeviceId=94944c77-931c-4cd3-aa23-889b9d8963f7

Plese find me solution

Comment: `When I am using with localhost `. Who is using localhost? When? From where?

Comment: from the local server. Dotnet application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing localhost:port from Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator)

Comment: Why are you comparing your app on an emulater with a completely different program? You should use your app on a real device. Your code is not working so show your code.

Comment: `When I am using with android emulator is not working `. You suggest here that your app when not using an emulator runs ok.

Comment: same code its working for the server but not to the localserver

Answer (score 0):

You can use real IP of computer(the computer that emulator is running, example: 192.168.103.45) . If still not work you could try use newer API level . In my case i use API level 22, 24 and real IP. It work ok.

Comment: I am using api level 24  even I checked with my system IP also like  http://192.168.0.5:51411/api/MobileAPI/Authenticate?UID=abc&PWD=123&DeviceId=94944c77-931c-4cd3-aa23-889b9d8963f7 Login request is null showing

Comment: please find me any solution.