# How to point to localhost:8000 with the Dart http package in Flutter?

Tags: http, dart, localhost, flutter

I'm following the [Flutter Networking/HTTP tutorial](https://flutter.io/networking/) to do a GET request to a server running on my localhost:8000. Visiting my localhost via my browser works fine. My code looks like this:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8000';
Future<String> getUnits(String category) async {
    var response = await httpClient.get('$url/$category');
    return response.body;
}
```

This works fine when I point to any real URL, such as `https://example.com`, but when I point to `https://localhost:8000` or `https://localhost` (or any variations of these), I get an error starting with:

```
E/flutter ( 4879): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 4879): SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 47060
E/flutter ( 4879): #0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:30:23)
```

The port in the error above changes each time I reload the app. I looked in the [http package code](https://github.com/dart-lang/http) and it doesn't seem like there is a way to specify the port for the URL. How do I point to my localhost?

Comment: This might help https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html

Comment: for anyone having this issue on iis/express check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367151/bad-request-400-requesting-asp-net-core-3-0-from-flutter

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: You can pass an Uri instead of a string as parameter

```
      var client = createHttpClient();
      client.get(new Uri.http("locahost:8000", "/category"));
```

Comment: I think httpClient.get can only take one input argument - I passed your answer in and it said `Too many positional arguments: 1 expected, but 3 found.`

Comment: Oh, you're using `createHttpClient` instead of `new HttpClient` my bad. Edited

Comment: That also resulted in the IO Error with a randomly chosen port. I think it usually would work, but I'm running the code in the Android emulator, which runs in a VM. So apparently I'm supposed to just point to 10.0.2.2 instead.

Comment: I am having the same error this is my code,I am able to get the response in the browser                                                                        
Future connect() async {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var request = await httpClient.get('127.0.0.1', 3000, "/api");
    var response = await request.close();

Comment: I believe the actual issues is caused by localhost reference on the Android emulator

Answer (score 83):

Replacing the string `localhost` with `10.0.2.2` resolved it for me, since I was running the code in the Android emulator, which is running in a VM. It's essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator).

Answer (score 45):

replace 'localhost' in your url to wifi connection ip e.g :
'http://localhost:8000' => 'http://192.168.1.102:8000'.
you can get your wifi ip from command prompt with cmd>ipconfig (wireless LAN adapter WI-FI.

```
var url = 'http://192.168.1.102:8000';
Future<String> getUnits(String category) async {
    var response = await httpClient.get('$url/$category');
    return response.body;
}
```

Comment: this will work. But you have to make sure you add a binding to your locahost or you run your app on 192.168.1.102:8000 otherwise it will give “Bad Request-Invalid Hostname” When accessing localhost from emulators

Comment: the new flutter will not accept strings for the url.  you will need :: var url=Uri.parse(your_string_path)

Comment: Hi, I am still having same issue after I tried to change the host to my ipv4 address or localhost or wifi ip... the issue still persists...Can you let me know how to fix it? not: using flask as backend

Comment: The Uri class also cannot parse IPv4 addresses in strings (frustrating!)

Answer (score 26):

Try forwarding the port of your emulator or the device to your computers port

e.g if your server is running on localhost:8000 then run this command

`adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000`

this command actually redirects your phone’s port 8000 to your computer’s port 8000.And now your client should be able to talk to the server running locally

Tip: this also works if you want to run your flutter web app on
your phone locally using

```
flutter run -d web-server
```

[more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68223713/8253662)

Comment: this flutter localhost command (adb reverse tcp:8000 tcp:8000) helps me a lot :) thank u

Answer (score 24):

If you are using an Android emulator then `localhost` on the emulator is not `127.0.0.0` it is `10.0.2.2`, so, on Android emulator you need to write `https://10.0.2.2:8000`, the `https://127.0.0.1:8000` will not work on real device too. because `localhost` means something different on real device.

For more information on how to connect a Flutter app to `localhost` on emulator or on a real device click on the link [Connecting Flutter application to Localhost](https://medium.com/@podcoder/connecting-flutter-application-to-localhost-a1022df63130)

Comment: Thank you! I was messing around for a while and this worked perfectly fine for me!

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, so apparently, I found a solution for this problem, so because you are in a virtual environment with your phone you cant use the localhost because the phone is not connected with your PC so simply, in my case, it worked, just use:

```
10.0.2.2:PORT
```

use this URL with your Port and it should work :)

Comment: how to get the port?

Comment: i used http://10.0.2.2:8000/login , bu it is giving this error ,  SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 39692

Answer (score 6):

im using ubuntu 20LTS, laravel backend, flutter http package.

- Step 1: in terminal run `sudo apt-get install net-tools` . this package supports `ifconfig` command to work.
- Step 2: in terminal run `ifconfig` . then in the output search this line `inet 192.168.43.217  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255` .  then copy the `inet 192.168.43.217` ip-address. also, note that ip-address will be different for you. for me it is `192.168.43.217` .
- Step 3: goto your laravel project `cd your_laravel_project` and then run `sudo php -S 192.168.43.217:81 -t public` to serve to inet address.
- Step 4: then from flutter `static const _apiRoute = "http://192.168.43.217:81/api/login".`
  huh!! this worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

if it is still not working even after pointing to 10.0.:2.2:port
Most likely Android is not allowing the http traffic.

change the AndroidManifest.xml
android/app/src/main

include

```
 android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

as shown below

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmvvap/ic_vvlauncher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Answer (score 5):

to find ip is `ifconfig` mac / linux

```sh
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500


    this one => inet 192.168.43.57 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.43.255

    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

start php

`php -S 192.168.43.57:5000 index.php`

than declare on future

```dart
Future<String> getIsi()async{
      final res = await new Dio().get('http://192.168.43.57:5000/lihat-isi');
      print('res.data');
      return res.data;
    }
```

an result is

```sh
I/flutter ( 3250): [{"id":"1","judul":"asasa","gambar":"asa","ket":"asa"},{"id":"2","judul":"asasa","gambar":"asa","ket":"asa"},{"id":"3","judul":"asasa","gambar":"asa","ket":"asa"},{"id":"4","judul":"asasa","gambar":"asa","ket":"asa"}]
```

Answer (score 5):

If your backend is on LARAVEL, make sure to serve the domain to your IP address and port before using it on your flutter application

To serve do this

`php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.100 --port=8000`

That should solve the problem.

Comment: what to do if using valet? that to on windows :P

Comment: Thanks so much. I am developing an app with flutter and laravel as backend

Answer (score 4):

Localhost via the computer browser I assume?

Using "http://localhost:port" in the Flutter code points to the local emulator device and not the local server running on your coomputer.

Point url to the IP Address of your server machine instead, that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to access localhost api through emulator, Change localhost to your IPV4 Address. And if you are running your api in Visual Studio set the app URL also to be IPV4 address.
In my case I changed it from "localhost:5001" to 192.168.XX.XX:5001

if you don't change the backend it will return “Bad Request-Invalid Hostname” When accessing localhost from emulators

[image]

Comment: Thanks, man it helped me a lot because while running the app on an emulator makes my pc slow and while running it on a real device it is working awesome I mean the app is running smooth and pc too.

Answer (score 2):

https://ngrok.com/download

Download ngrokand run `ngrok http <your localhost URL>`
*(Please run this command in same location where you are download ngrok.exe)*
EX `ngrok http http://127.0.0.1:8000`

After that you will get URL forwarder link like `http://98b9-2402-4000-2380-c5a6-c5c9-86cf-ea4d-66af.ngrok.io` and change your base URL to this.

That's it! Enjoy and happy coding!!