# Android emulator studio cant access hostname on window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, flutter

I'm building flutter project to access localhost machine using http, the problem android emulator cant access host-name. I want to get url working for api that provide json.

Edit file system32/drive/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 hipiapp.test

192.xxx.xx.xx localhost
192.xxx.xx.xx hipiapp.test
```

Error if connect without ipaddress(this link work if use normal web browser but not in android studio)

```
final String urlApi = 'http://hipiapp.test/api/index';
'hipiapp.test' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)
```

if I use full with my ip , error url not found.

```
final String urlApi = 'http://192.xxx.xx.xx/hipiapp.test/api/index';
```

Comment: You are aware that the emulator has its own `localhost`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855754/unable-to-make-calls-to-localhost-using-flutter-random-port-being-assigned-to-h/49855877#49855877 might help you.

Comment: Does your server app on `192.xxx.xx.xx` listen to the public interface or only to 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Only 192.xxx.xx.xx. change to adb reverse --list
host-12 tcp:5000 tcp:5000 still cant use http://hipiapp.test/api/index

Comment: Your emulator would need to find a DNS that resolves `http://hipiapp.test/api/index`, but because it's not a registered domain it can't resolve it. You should be able to connect to a server listening on your development machine on port 5000 using `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html has some more suggestions

Comment: SOLVED, Sorry,not mention you earlier that api was requested from my local laravel 5.6 development. Solve the issue run php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 and use http://192.xxx.xx.xx:8000/api/index Thank you for your assisting.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like the issue was caused by a conflicting network address where another host is serve. To solve this issue, you can either [change the network address where the emulator is running](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking) or change the address of the conflicting deployment.