# Connection refused when trying to connect local host with my own <keyvaluepair> values

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, socketexception

I want to connect my localhost and take a token with my parameters.When I was connecting in my device with this code I have an error connection refused!

Here is my code.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

      var formContent = {
        "grant_type": "1",
        "branchcode": "0",
        "password": "1",
        "username": "1",
        "dbname": "1",
        "dbuser": "1",
        "dbpassword": "1",
        "dbtype": "0"
      };

      Future<String> getData() async {
        var postBody= json.encode(formContent);
        var response = await http.post(
            Uri.encodeFull("http://localhost:7070/api/v2/token"),
            body:postBody,
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
        if(response.statusCode == 200){
          return String.fromCharCode(json.decode(response.body));
        }else{
          throw Exception('Failed');
        }
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
          body: new Center(
            child: new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Get The Data"),
              onPressed: getData,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I cannot connect my localhost with my own  values. I have an error like connection refused but I don't understand why ?

```
Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 40109
```

Comment: You are aware that `localhost` is the phone/emulator and not your development PC? You can either use `adb` to create a redirect or use the public IP address of your PC to connect from the phone if the service you try to connect to listens on that IP and your phone is connected to the same network (WiFi).

Comment: Yes ı know that so how can ı solve it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855754/unable-to-make-calls-to-localhost-using-flutter-random-port-being-assigned-to-h/49855877#49855877 might help and not using `localhost` as mentioned above.

Comment: I cannot understand how ı am use this adb reverse —list command

Comment: I don’t understand what ı am exactly do

Comment: When ı change localhost to my ip adress, ı have same error

Answer (score 0):

The error given is usually caused either by the device/emulator having no network connectivity, or by the given endpoint being unreachable (i.e. server is offline, incorrect address). If the issue was caused by the latter, you can try replacing the root address from 'localhost' to '10.0.2.2'. This is because the emulator intercepts the address and translates it to '127.0.0.1' - more details about this is explained here https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking