# Flutter iPhone http port assigned randomly

Tags: http, flutter

I am trying to connect to local server with http request from flutter app in iPhone.

I have this error

`SocketException: OS Error: Operation timed out, errno = 60, address = IPfromMyMachine, port = 65353`

Saw a lot of solution from online which is to fix anroid but not iOS. Anyone can help with this?

Comment: This is not the server port. It is the client port.

Comment: @Ryosuke so even if my server is running port 8000 will not affect anything?

Comment: yeah it won't. Just make sure you are giving right server port in your request.

Comment: what IP are you using for your local server?

Comment: @Ryosuke i get it from ifconfig as my phone and my laptop are connected to the same wifi

Comment: does it work when you run it in the simulator with localhost:port as your endpoint?

Comment: @Ryosuke I used the different IP for my android simulator which is 10.0.2.2. it does not work if i use the same ip from the ifconfig for android simulator.

Comment: yeah I know localhost is for iOS simulator and 10.0.2.2 for android. I just asked that if it works or not. Now it only comes down to your firewall and other networking stuff.

Comment: @Ryosuke now i get SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 61, address = MYIP, port = 53997 instead of connection timeout. I do not know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by assigning the local ip to a DNS record.

e.g local.your_domain.com points to 192.168.1.10

Then replace the IP address with the url and it should work fine