# SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 in flutter using django backend

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, pythonanywhere

I m building a flutter app with django rest-framework. The registration api is working fine in Postman but after some successful registration from the flutter app it is showing the above error. The request is been sent on https address.

Removed csrf. Nothing happens.

## Request:

```
var data = {'email':signupemailidcontroller.text,
            'password1':passwordcontroller.text,
            'password2':confirmpasswordcontroller.text,
           };
        //http request here
        await http.post(websitesignupurl,
                        headers: headers,
                        body: json.encode(data))
          .then((onResponse){
            print(onResponse.body);
          }).catchError((onerror){
            print(onerror.toString());
        });
```

## Output in Console:

SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111

I Expect the response of this request to be a Json object containing the user and token.

Comment: Harnish if the answer I have given below helped you, do consider marking it as the accepted answer. So that we can help others who have the same question.

Comment: is this being run on PythonAnywhere? if you have a free user account, then you will only be able to make http posts to endpoints on the PythonAnywhere whitelist https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Harnish, need a few more details in-order to debug this error.

1. Are you running the server locally or communicating with a remote server?
2. Are you running the app on the Android Emulator?

**Possible Solution:**

If you're running the server locally and using the Android emulator, then your server endpoint should be `10.0.2.2:8000` instead of `localhost:8000` as AVD uses `10.0.2.2` as an alias to your host loopback interface (i.e) `localhost`

**Note on Futures**

I noticed above that the code is using await and then on the same line. This can be confusing, to be clear, `await` is used to suspend execution until a future completes, and `then` is a callback function to execute after a future completed. The same could be written as below

```
void myFunction() async {
    var data = {};
    var response = await http.post(URL, headers:headers, body:data);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(reponse.body);
    } else {
       print('A network error occurred');
    }
}
```

or the non async/await method

```
void myFunction() {
    var data = {};
    http.post(URL, headers:headers, body:data)
    .then((response) => print(response.body))
    .catchError((error) => print(error));
}
```

For a more detailed information on Futures in Dart please read 
https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: What should be the host link if I want to run the application on my physical phone?
Also how would things work if I upload the application on google play store what would be the host link then?

Comment: i am facing same issue with Remote server

Comment: @chaitanyaHarde To run a server on your local machine and be able to access it on your physical device, you would need use the `adb reverse` command with the appropriate `tcp port` for your application as mentioned above. 
When the application is on the playstore, you would need to use a server configured on a publicly accessible IP address or domain

Comment: Using http://10.0.2.2:8000/ as the base URL while connecting to a local server through an Android virtual device worked perfectly for me! Thanks!

Comment: I have solved my problem  with : `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and if its solve yours upvote @joão-garcia-de-lima-neto 's unswer below. (thanks body)

Answer (score 38):

I went to the terminal and used `ifconfig` command

I got my IP address: `192.168.0.109`

[image]

Then I simply replaced this IP address with my "localhost" in flutter app http requests. And it worked like a charm!

Comment: Inside terminal running ipconfig command gave me IPV4 address: `192.168.1.101`

Then I simply replaced this IP address with my `127.0.0.1:8000` in flutter app
`http` requests. And it worked like a charm!

For `Laravel` : `php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.101 --port 80`

Answer (score 15):

- if in localhost instead localhost use the IP of your network
- hint:for find Ip in cmd run `ipconfig` and get the ipv4

1: Example:

```
await http.post("http://127.68.34.23/wp-json/...",
                    headers: headers,
                    body: json.encode(data))
```

if in server write the url of main in url

Comment: Hi! I'm stuck looking for answers. My problem is that when I get a "response", the backend returns an HTML file, and i dont know why. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm using xampp with mariadb, and as a backend I use php (aid with yii2 framework)

Comment: You must check your server in most place return api if get data from html no problem

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem running in a real device, and only changing the IP in API link doesn´t work.

The solution for me was to put the server run with the command below:

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then pass your machine IP to the API link instead of localhost, as the sample below:

```
http://192.168.0.67:8000
```

Comment: I have a flutter/djangoRest stack and after run the django for this 'all ip' that is set to zero the django report that my machine ip wasn't allowed, so I notice that in the settings.py of the django and add the string in the array `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.100.3']` so now my machine can be founded by the dio in my real phone. TY João

Answer (score 14):

In addition to Rohan's answer you can also read:

[Unable to make calls to Localhost using Flutter, random port being assigned to HTTP GET call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49855754/unable-to-make-calls-to-localhost-using-flutter-random-port-being-assigned-to-h/60653912#60653912)

I was trying to run my app on physical device using local server so, for that i had to use the below mentioned command, here keep in mind change the port number according to your own port number

```
adb reverse tcp:3001 tcp:3001
```

> As @maheshmnj pointed that this command is redirecting your phone's
>   port 3001 to your computer's port 3001. In case if you want to
>   redirect port 2000 of your phone to port 3000 of your computer then
>   you could do this `adb reverse tcp:2000 tcp:3000`

you can also read about adb and networking via going through below mentioned page
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: I was struggling for a long time. Thank you so much. Your solution worked out for me.

Comment: I would like to add to @taranjeetsingh's answer the command actually
redirects your phone’s port 3001 to your computer’s port 3001. In Case you would like to redirect port 2000 of your phone to computers port 3000,Then the command would be ``` adb reverse tcp:2000 tcp:3000```

Answer (score 8):

Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to your manifest. This solved this issue for me.

Comment: If you're having this problem on devices outside test environment this is the only solution

Answer (score 8):

This problem occurs when the endpoint are incorrect or your host and server backend (Example Laravel API)doesn't share the same IP address.

Solution is.

1. Connect your workspace (computer, emulator, devices) in the same
   network.
2. Find your IP by typing on terminal `ifconfig`.
3. If you build your API with Laravel, start the server appointing to `IP ADDRESS` of your computer, sudo `php artisan serve --host YOUR_COMPUTER_IP_ADDRESS --port NUMBER`

Example:

```
`sudo php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.11 --port 80`
```

4. Test your endpoint in Postman or similar Application and type `http://192.168.1.11:80/Your_Route`
5. If everything is working good, you can run with app. Go!!!

Answer (score 7):

I know that the question is too old, But I will answer this because this may be helpful to someone who has this problem.

Without more details, I can't give a specific solution. But with following conditions  can give a specific solution

- I imagine that the API host was in local computer
- I imagine that you use your emulator for running the app

The URL you tried with postman maybe something like this `http://127.0.0.1:[port number]/register` or `http://localhost:[port number]/register`. But this may not work with an emulator because it doesn't have access to that URL. To get access to the local host of your you need to find out the host address.

Follow these steps to get your host address.

- Click on the three dots(More) in the android emulator
- Setting -> Proxy
- You can change your host address if you like by selecting `Manual proxy configuration

Then you can see your `host name` with the `port number`. Then replace your URL with those like `http://10.0.0.2:5000/register`.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, make sense now :D. I was running the server on localhost and I expected to work on mobile.

Comment: Yeah, you have to change your IP. then it will work

Comment: what about macos and ios?

Comment: I can't give you a specific answer because I am not familiar with IOS.  So keep exploring you can find a solution.

Comment: I also had this same doubt for ios and macos BUT the thing smoothly works in the case of ios but not for macos. I am still not clear why!

Answer (score 5):

In C#[.net core api], go to launchSettings.json under Properties tab and change the follwing code to this(change localhost to 0.0.0.0 on applicationURl) and on the app(flutter), use ur local IPV4 IP. ex: (192.169.0.10)

```
"coreWebAPI": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000", 
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using 'localhost' in your url, change it to your ipv4 address and it will work

Answer (score 4):

Soltuion that worked on my machine

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1288], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.61.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

### STEP: 1 (get your ipv4)

in terminal/cmd type

- `ifconfig` for Mac/Linux/Unix
- `ipconfig` for Windows

you will get some result in windows it looks like [image]

### STEP: 2 (change your request url)

❌ Dont do

- `http.get('localhost/my-local-rest-api/etc'`
- `127.0.0.1//my-local-rest-api/etc`.

✅ Do

- **for android** `http.get('10.0.2.2/my-local-rest-api/etc`
- **for ios** `http.get('192.168.8.155/my-local-rest-api/etc`

## IMPORTANT

⚠ **always pass Uri instead of raw String
example**: `http.get(Uri.parse('my-url-in-raw-string'))`

## STEP 3: enable un-encrypted networking connections

### for Android

in `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest ...other params...>
   // STEP: 1 make sure you have INTERNET permission
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <application
        android:label="YourAppName"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> <-- STEP: 2 add this line
        <activity
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### for iOS

in `ios/Runner/Info.plist` add this

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

Recently I also faced a similar issue, there are a few things you try and check (its applicable for both flutter or android with any backend language):

**If you are testing on an android emulator**

1.You should first get the ipv4 of your PC ( for mac type this in terminal **ipconfig getifaddr en0**)

3. Use this ip address in URI (hostname) while sending the request.
4. Go to Emulator settings -> proxy and select Manual proxy configuration and paste your PC ip address and port number as your local server port usually 3000.
5. Restart your emulator (this is necessary).
6. It should work, if it's not working then restart your application and carefully check the whole URL. I am telling you this because I was passing extra '/' before.

**If you are testing on a physical device**

1. Make sure your device and PC are connected to the same network (using a mobile hotspot will be better).
2. Get the ipv4 of your PC from the terminal and use this in URI (hostname) while sending the request.
3. It should work, if it's not then check your URL carefully.

Comment: This is also was workable for me, but partially resources from internet wasn't get loaded, only data from backend server from localhost.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I had to change to fix the same error in my case:

- Start django with `python manage.py runserver 0:8000` and not just `python manage.py runserver` (0:8000 is the abbreviation for 0.0.0.0:8000 and makes your web application visible on your local network - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver)
- In your flutter app specify the server address using your pc local ip, i.e.  instead of http://localhost:8000 use something like http://192.168.1.2:8000. To retrieve your current ip address run `ipconfig` in the terminal if on Windows, otherwise `ifconfig`.
- Update  allowed host in django settings if necessary. For example set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*', ]` (but only in your dev environment!)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to get your public PC IP and use it in your URL for example:
http://192.168.0.67:3000, where 3000 is the port no.

Answer (score 2):

For mac users to check ip address

in terminal type: `ipconfig getifaddr en0` and use that Ip address as below

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

class AuthAction {
  static String BASE_URL = 'http://192.168.0.105:27017/';

  static Future<Null> signUpAction(
      firstName, lastName, email, password, userName) async {
    try {
      http.Response res = await http.post( Uri.parse(BASE_URL + 'signUp' ));
      print(res);

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);

        // Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'err');
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: I did not touch the port on which my mongo-node server is running. Which is 27017

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution in the world but a good workaround is to install **ngrok** and link your localhost to it. Worked fine for me and it's very fast to setup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Had same issue only on android simulator on Iphone simulator through all OK, ngrok was really working solution for me. To try using ngrok you need sign up and install it, than run with specifing protocol and port like: "[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) http 3000"  P.S. adding user-permissions wasn't helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this with `$ adb tcpip <port-your-local-server>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in flutter with spring backend. Instead of using
'http://localhost:8080/' in my requests, I changed this to 'http://143.235.7.641:8080/' where '143.235.7.641' is my Wi-Fi IPv4 address, and it  worked.

(NOTE : I assume you are testing flutter in physical phone,and phone and computer are connected the same wi-fi.)

Comment: Hi, I tried using ipv4 add of my wfi ,it still gives me the same error ``` Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 53182``` my backend is in flask-socektio. The flask-socketio never runs on localhost idk y. If I give host='localhost; it says this ```  wsgi starting up on http://[::1]:5000``. Can u tell me how to fix this? also how to connect to flutter ?

Answer (score 1):

add in you Androidmenifest file project->app->src->AndroidManifest.xml

[image: add these two line at top of menifest file as this picture shows]

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 1):

**Title: Connecting Flutter App on Physical Device to Flask Server**

**Solution**
Follow these steps to achieve the desired connection:

Run Flask Server:

Start your Flask server and make it accessible over the network using the following command:

```
flask run --debug --host 0.0.0.0
```

Find Your Machine's IP Address:

Obtain your machine's IP address (IPv4) by running the following command (on Ubuntu):

```
hostname -I
```

Replace localhost with this IP address in your Flutter app code.

Update Flutter App Code:

In your Flutter app, replace references to localhost with your machine's IP address obtained in the previous step. Update the URLs or endpoints accordingly.

Example:

```
final serverUrl = 'http://your_machine_ip:5000/endpoint';
```

Connect Devices to the Same Wi-Fi Network:

Ensure that your physical device and your development machine (running the Flask server) are connected to the same Wi-Fi network.

Access the Flask Server from Flutter App:

Run your Flutter app on the physical device, and it should be able to access the Flask server using the updated IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue once,
After going through some overly complicated stackoverflow answers and google search, finally i figure it out,
In this case you are most likely to be using a android emulator, So just turn on the mobile data on the emulator then try it again, i'm sure that this time it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
final response = await client.post(
    "http://192.xxx.xx.xx/api/signin", 
    headers: {"Authorization": apiKey},
    body: jsonEncode({
      "username": username,
      "password": password,
    }));
```

Even I had got a SocketException Error but I replaced my IP address and didn't mention any Port number and it worked for me, and if I mention the port number it would throw an error.
Hoping this would work out.

I am using Flask for backend ,using blocs.

Answer (score 0):

Try ths link delay the fuction and your will not get this error

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    widget.callback();
  });
```

[It Work for me](https://github.com/hillelcoren/flutter-redux-starter/issues/16#issuecomment-994369879)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on real phone, then you will get this error even if you add your localhost address to allowed host.
For me, connecting my laptop to my phone's hotspot and running django server with laptop's ipv4 address (which you can find by using ipconfig command) by python manage.py runserver 192.168.**.**:8000 i.e. your ipv4 address:port number, than you will be able to access django server using your phone's browser as well, now add this your ipv4 address to your allowed host. And, change your url from localhost or 127.0.0.1 to your ipv4 address. I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#### Replace your URL with:

```
Uri.parse("YourURL").replace(host: "YourIPAddress");
```

**Explanation:** This error means your host-address isn't correct (as already in above answers pointed out). As you probably have a physical device it must access the emulator server you hooked up to your computer (aka your IP adress).

*How to get my IP-Adress?*

MAC: `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'`

WINDOWS: `netsh interface ip show address | findstr "IP Address"`

Answer (score 0):

I had an error with **local server** (json server) in flutter:

**The connection errored: Connection refused This indicates an error which most likely cannot be solved by the library. OSError (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111)**

Solution:

1. Run

```
    json-server --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3000 --watch db.json
```

2. Handle platform url

```
  String get baseUrl {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      return 'http://localhost:3000';
    }

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'http://10.0.2.2:3000';
    }

    return 'http://127.0.0.1:3000';
  }
```