# Flutter SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 51500)

Tags: flutter, strapi

I am Using strapi.io open Source Node.js Headless CMS

this is my code for registerpage

void _registerUser() async {

```
http.Response response =
    await http.post('http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register', body: {
  "username": _userName,
  "email": _email,
  "password": _password,
});
final responseData = json.decode(response.body);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
  return print(responseData);
} else {
  // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
  throw Exception('Failed to load post');
}
```

}

any idea how to solve this

[Problem about Socket exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NgyC.jpg)

**update:**

Found the Solution:
If you're running the server locally and using the Android emulator, then your server endpoint should be 10.0.2.2:8000 instead of localhost:8000 as AVD uses 10.0.2.2 as an alias to your host loopback interface (i.e) localhost

clear explanation checkout this Answer:

[SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 in flutter using django backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785581/socketexception-os-error-connection-refused-errno-111-in-flutter-using-djan)

Thank you So much Everyone For Helping me!!❤❤❤

Comment: Is your strapi app running in your localhost when you run the this code

Comment: Yeah !!!! Strapi server running in the background

Comment: If I Visit http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register then it's saying {"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}

Comment: Look at my answer already given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994991/11874673

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 in flutter using django backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785581/socketexception-os-error-connection-refused-errno-111-in-flutter-using-djan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For MAC Users**

Instead of `localhost`, put your `MAC IP address`. Mobile will not understand localhost.

Click

> apple logo > system prefrences > Network

Under connected networks you can find your wifi ip

after that instead of

> http://localhost:1337

you can use your wifi ip

> http://192.168.2.250

[image]

Answer (score 17):

1 open cmd

2 run `ipconfig` at cmd

3 copy IPv4 Address from cmd

4 at 'http://localhost:1337/auth/local/register' replace 'localhost' with your IPv4 Address

5 run your app

Answer (score 10):

Instead of localhost, put your machine IP address. Mobile doesnt understand localhost.

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me!!
Insert your local IP address (192.168.x.x) instead of localhost.
You can find it by writing **ipconfig** on Windows CMD and by writing **ifconfig** on Linux Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

just check if you have given the internet permission and the you have good internet connection

Comment: Yeah, I add Internet permission but still the Same Result and Even have a good internet connection !!

Answer (score 0):

Use this library [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for fetching data, And don't declare response as *final* and *http.Response*, instead of this you can use **var**

Comment: DioError (DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 51694)

Comment: Do you follow this ?

Comment: brutal answer. delete now

Answer (score 0):

I had de same issue, it was caused because I builded an app version with signed  on debug mode, on Android Studio, it was ok. But later on when I tried to run on the app on visual studio the error appears!!, so I went to Android Studio in normal mode, and runned the app , the error desapears. Because these error only appeeared in Android versión.