# Flutter / Dart Error SocketException: OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection. , errno = 1225, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 59250

Tags: flutter, dart, localhost

I am getting this error in my debugger.
From what I understood it's an error generated by ip config.

I found this solve here, but i dont understand where should i modify it. where should i change the ip address?
[Flutter SocketException (SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = localhost, port = 51500)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001536/flutter-socketexception-socketexception-os-error-connection-refused-errno)

```
ERROR - 2021-03-23 18:21:26.074284
PUT /SXUs66yGd7s=/
Error thrown by handler.
SocketException: OS Error: The remote computer refused the network connection.
, errno = 1225, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 59250
```

Help!
Thank you alot

Comment: Could you post the part of code that's causing it?

Comment: What are you trying to connect to? Post your code with the url you are trying to communicate with.

Comment: How can I identify the part of the code that is causing it?

Comment: Is this your code throwing the error or is it the debugger itself? If the former, show your code. If the latter, what device/emulator are you trying to run your app on?

Comment: I had 2 vs codes open, and when I was debugging the one that I was working, it was intercalating with the other one. Wired! It has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was going through this trouble myself
i just disconnect the emulator and restated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your environment:
for me->
I tried to run windows app with xampp localhost and received this error.
then i changed my uri in frontend to

```
String uri = 'http://127.0.0.1/db-name';
```

after that, all working.
in the emulator the uri is different.

```
String uri = 'http://your ip addres/db-name';
```

to get your ip address->
open cmd and run "ipconfig"

use ipv4.