# facing socket exception in flutter(warning in console),error no-111

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, dart

I am trying to enter into my flutter app and it is showing this error,infact api is also working fine and getting the right response.but still facing
**SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = "", port = 50000**

Comment: Can you share your source code ?

Comment: pardon,but code is confidential,i cant share it

Comment: but i can tell you that this error was sudden otherwise it was working fine

Comment: where did you run your app? in simlator or real device? ios or android? Have you added internet permissions?

Comment: in both emulator and physical device ,with internet permissions given

Comment: does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785581/socketexception-os-error-connection-refused-errno-111-in-flutter-using-djan