# SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 44164

Tags: python, flutter, dart, flask

In my flutter app I am using the flask server for testing purpose. I started my server and run the API url in my flutter app. But **SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 44164.**  error is showing.

```
var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
      var request =
          http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:5000/addrec'));
      request.body = json.encode({
        "name": UploadedName,
        "grade": Uploadedgrade,
        "loaction": Uploadedlocation,
        "like": Uploadedlike,
        "admission": Uploadedadmission,
        "comments": Uploadedcomments,
        "entery_time": UploadeddataentryTime
      });
      request.headers.addAll(headers);

      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
      } else {
        print(response.reasonPhrase);
      }
```

I am using actual android device for app running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111 in flutter using django backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785581/socketexception-os-error-connection-refused-errno-111-in-flutter-using-djan)

Comment: I am running server locally in my PC and I am using android device not emulator.

Comment: then u can use ur ipaddress with the port

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because the `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`) on the device is only accessible to the device itself.

### Solution 1

You can reverse-proxy a `localhost` port to the Android device/emulator running `adb reverse` on the command prompt like so:

```
adb reverse tcp:5000 tcp:5000
```

### Solution 2

Use the machine's IP address where the API is running. Also, the API should be listening to the IP `0.0.0.0` to be accessible outside the localhost.

Supposing the API machine's IP is `192.168.1.123` it's going to be something like:

```dart
Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.123:5000/addrec')
```

Just take care because changing the API to listen to `0.0.0.0` is a security risk as the API is going to be accessible to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way as far as you use the python server with dynamic ip 0.0.0.0:port

you can just use  linux  shell

> ipconfig

or windows is

> ifconfig

to get ur pc ipaddress and access the port

then you use the

> ipaddress:port