# How to use Flutter http request when the url contain port?

Tags: android, json, ajax, flutter, dart

I am trying to send post request to a website with port configured. http://example.com:8080/. When i send the request, it show some error

```
http.post('example.com:8080/apps/api.php', body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'}).then((response) {
  print(response);
});
```

> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'example.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

The port is ignored there. Is there any way i can do to fix this? Or is there any other http library that i can use?

Comment: The port ignored? It does not come as far. The server example.com cannot be found you mean.

Comment: Can you please update your Question, with some code, How your are sending a request. ?

Comment: @KumarLokeshRathod Added.

Comment: maybe this [SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372568/how-to-point-to-localhost8000-with-the-dart-http-package-in-flutter/56078898) could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a port issue. Make sure you set the **correct permissions** in the Android manifest file (*android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*) to be able to make HTTP calls from your Android app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

More details on that [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27883) and the official documentation from Android on permissions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview).

Answer (score 0):

If you have added this line
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
at android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
then try restarting emulator or computer itself.
In my case, I restarted my laptop and it was fine. Most of the times restarting computer will solve the problems like this.