# How make local http request in flutter?

Tags: django, flutter

I'm making an app, and i already have a server running in my local. I can acess trought my navigator the url:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4444/categorie?page_size=15&page=1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4444
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Preview:

```
{
    "count": 4,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "uid": "_b656062d3754",
            "name": "Pinga"
        },
        {
            "uid": "_0c644473c244",
            "name": "Cerveja"
        },
        {
            "uid": "_75df557ccbaa",
            "name": "Vinhos"
        },
        {
            "uid": "_8e32ce3baded",
            "name": "Refrigerantes"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when i try in flutter, the request never respond:

```
getCategories() async {

  String url = 'http://localhost:4444/categorie?page_size=15&page=1';

  var response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
    return response.body;
  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```

I'm running the server in my `Windows10` using `Django`. And my flutter app is in the `Android Studio` using a `Virtual Machine` as device.
I tryed to change the ip to `127.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.1` but still not working. Have i change the host of Django or enable any configuration in my flutter or inside `VirutalBox`?

- Request to other sites is working well. The problem is in local.

My dependencies:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: any

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47379000/9609442

Comment: @ViniciusMorais Did my answer solve your issue? If so, please mark it as correct.

Comment: No sorry, i had to change my Django configuration to solve my problem and change the IP from url request.

Answer (score 5):

Your localhost on your PC is not the same on your Android emulator. To access your PC's localhost from the Android emulator, you need to point to `10.0.2.2`.

This means that you need to change your code to:

```
String url = 'http://10.0.2.2:4444/categorie?page_size=15&page=1';
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this in `pubspec` file under dependencies:

```
http: ^0.12.0+2
```

**Use this method for Http request**

```
getCategories() async {
    final response = await http.get("http://localhost:4444/categorie?page_size=15&page=1",

      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body);

      var list = result['results'] as List;
    //  make a model class
      List<Categories> categories_= list.map((i) => Categories.fromJson(i)).toList();
      setState(() => {
      // update value
      });
    } else {
 setState(() => {
       // Show error
      });

    }

  }
```

**Model class:**

```
class Categories{
  String uid;
  String name;

  Categories({this.uid, this.name});

  Categories.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    uid = json['uid'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['uid'] = this.uid;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```