flutter pwa closes keyboard
I develop a PWA with flutter and deploy it on server. when launching it on mobile, after typing a text, keyboard closes automatically. but I want keyboard be open. How can I do that? can anyone help me?
GestureDetector(
      onTap:()async {
    if (!messageController.isEmptyPureText) {


    //sending message via socket

      messageController.clear();
      isTextEntered.value = false;

    }
  },
      child: Container(
        width: AppConstants.defaultMessengerBottomSheetHeight - 5,
        height: AppConstants.defaultMessengerBottomSheetHeight,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.3,
          child: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.images.svg.send),
        ),
      ),
    )


Can you share the code? Was it working during debugging?

I updated question. this is a button in textfield. I don't know how to test while debuging. It happens in mobile browser.

Textfield is not present in the code. you can test your code on mobile browser using https://stackoverflow.com/a/70787804/14466860
