# Opening flutter web on a phone using dekstop mode

Tags: android, flutter, dart, browser

I am currently building a flutter web and I have devided into 3 parts of screen ui (ui for desktop, tab, and phone). So let's say when the width of the screen in X<500 (phone ui), 500<=X<1000 (tab ui), X>1000 (desktop ui). So far, it runs well but the thing is... when I open it in browser of my phone and use desktop mode (Desktop site) the content doesn't work properly (I would like to show desktop ui when Desktop mode is on), like I can not press the button and scroll the web. Is there a way so that flutter web can run well in phone browser when Desktop mode is on ?