# Flutter web on mobile device

Tags: flutter, dart, browser

Hi I am trying to open my flutter web project on browser of my phone. I turn on the `Desktop mode` on my phone browser, and the UI will be the same like I open it in my pc, the case is.. all of the button is unable to be pressed on phone browser, while on my pc it is working fine. Is there a way to solve this case? I also open this case on [Opening flutter web on a phone using dekstop mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75926555/opening-flutter-web-on-a-phone-using-dekstop-mode)