# Flutter web renders correctly in desktop mode but not in mobile screen mode when I run the application from VS code

Tags: flutter, flutter-renderflex-error

My Flutter Web application is rendering perfectly when I run it on a desktop browser as seen below. I have not used the full width of the screen for the game since the layout looks better as a narrow strip similar to a mobile in portrait mode. However, when I reduce the screen width to that of a mobile browser, only the appbar renders and the rest of the game does not render as seen in the second image. I tried all the options suggested in this  SOF issue but none of them have worked: [Flutter web app not working on mobile browser. How to debug the error if running flutter code on mobile browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69332371/flutter-web-app-not-working-on-mobile-browser-how-to-debug-the-error-if-running?rq=4)

[image]  [image]

Here is the code that I have:

```
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  auth = FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: app);

  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'WORDSUITE',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: const Color(0xffc3e1f3),
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.interTextTheme(),
        ),
        home: const FrontPage(),
        routes: {
          '/result': (context) => const ResultScreen(),
        });
  }
}

class _FrontPageState extends ConsumerState<FrontPage> {

...
...
@override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(),
      body: (userScore.isInit)
          ? const Center(child: Loading())
          : Center(
              child: Container(
                width: userScore.boxwidth,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffe5e1da)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Consumer(builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, _) {
                      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                      return Hints();
                    }),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    FittedBox(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  userScore.setActiveBoxValue(0);
                                });
                              },
                              child: WordBox(
                                wordList.todaysword?.firstpuzzle ?? [],
                                userScore.activeBox[0],
                                0,
                                refresh,
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(width: 5),
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  userScore.setActiveBoxValue(1);
                                });
                              },
                              child: WordBox(
                                  wordList.todaysword?.secondpuzzle ?? [],
                                  userScore.activeBox[1],
                                  1,
                                  refresh)),
                          const SizedBox(width: 5),
                          GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  userScore.setActiveBoxValue(2);
                                });
                              },
                              child: WordBox(
                                  wordList.todaysword?.thirdpuzzle ?? [],
                                  userScore.activeBox[2],
                                  2,
                                  refresh)),
                          const SizedBox(width: 10),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    SizedBox(
                      // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
                      width: userScore.boxwidth * 0.95,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                        child: Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          decoration:
                              const BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xfffbf9f1)),
                          child: FlexiText(
                              wordList.todaysword?.fourthpuzzle ?? '',
                              userScore.activeBox[3],
                              3,
                              refresh),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    FittedBox(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => activateHint(HintType.sp),
                            // style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                            //   backgroundColor:
                            //       const Color.fromARGB(113, 60, 181, 218),
                            // ),
                            child: Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Image.asset('assets/images/btn.png'),
                                const Text(
                                  '#L',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 28, color: Colors.black),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => activateHint(HintType.ltr),
                            child: Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Image.asset('assets/images/btn.png'),
                                const Text(
                                  'LTR',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 28, color: Colors.black),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => activateHint(HintType.ba),
                            child: Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Image.asset('assets/images/btn.png'),
                                const Text(
                                  'B/A',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 28, color: Colors.black),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => rvlHint(),
                            child: Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Image.asset('assets/images/btn.png'),
                                const Text(
                                  'RVL',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 28, color: Colors.black),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 80),
                    MyKeyboard(
                      onTextInput: (myText) {
                        _insertText(myText);
                      },
                      onBackspace: () {
                        _backspace();
                      },
                      onEnter: () {
                        _onEnter();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
```

Can someone please guide me as to what might be going wrong? One other thing I would like to mention is this. If I resize the window from desktop size to mobile size, the application resizes just fine. However if I set the browser to mobile size using F12 and reload the app, the game does not render (as shown in the second image). I am not getting any error or any overflow of pixels in the debug logs so not getting a clue as to where the renderer is failing

Answer (score 0):

MediaQuery Class could be used to create responsive layout class.
refer this website [geekforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-managing-the-mediaquery-object/)
I have seen that your did not used MediaQuery class even once

Comment: Hi ... thanks for writing in. My apologies - I havent included that part of code cos it was getting too long. I have used a provider referenced by userscore. I have a parameter there called boxwidth which is based on MediaQuery as below

Comment: scrwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
      userScore.checkDeviceType(scrwidth);        void checkDeviceType(double scrwidth) {
    if (scrwidth < 850) {
      platform = 1; // mobile
    } else if (scrwidth < 1100) {
      platform = 2; // tablet
    } else {
      platform = 3; // desktop

      if (platform < 3) {
        boxwidth = scrwidth * 0.9;
      } // for mobiles and tablets
      else {
        boxwidth = min(500, scrwidth * 0.5); // for desktop
      }
    }
  }