# Flutter: can't connect to localhost API

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localhost, asp.net-web-api2

i have this kind of prob, i want integrate Flutter with .Net core web API. im new to flutter so, i just followed the tutorial but the i cant connected to localhost api

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:testproject_flutter/Service/model/models.dart';

class ServiceDataProvider {
  final _baseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api';
  final http.Client httpClient;

  ServiceDataProvider({required this.httpClient});

  Future<Service> createService(Service service) async {
    final response = await httpClient.post(
      Uri.http('http://localhost:5000', '/api/services'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "serviceName": service.ServiceName,
        "description": service.Description,
        "category": service.Category,
        "initialPrice": service.InitialPrice,
        "intermediatePrice": service.IntermediatePrice,
        "advancedPrice": service.AdvancedPrice,
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Service.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to create course.');
    }
  }

  Future<List<Service>> getServices() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get('$_baseUrl/services' as Uri);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final services = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
        return services.map((service) => Service.fromJson(service)).toList();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load courses');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception("Exception throuwn $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteService(int id) async {
    final http.Response response = await http.delete(
      'http://localhost:5000/Service/$id' as Uri,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to delete course.');
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateService(Service service) async {
    final http.Response response = await httpClient.put(
      'http://localhost:5000/Service/' as Uri,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        "serviceId": service.id,
        "serviceName": service.ServiceName,
        "description": service.Description,
        "category": service.Category,
        "initialPrice": service.InitialPrice,
        "intermediatePrice": service.IntermediatePrice,
        "advancedPrice": service.AdvancedPrice,
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to update course.');
    }
  }
}
```

this is service_data.dart from flutter i copy and modified to follow latest flutter package, i try to connect to several address to replace `localhost` with `0.0.0.0` , `192.168.42.232` , `127.0.0.1` but still has no changed, this is my program.cs , i use .net7 controller api

```
using fixit.Data;
using fixit.Models;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);



// Add services to the container

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebApiDatabase")));
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddCors(option =>
            {
                option.AddPolicy("allowedOrigin",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()
                    );
            });
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRepository<Service>, ServiceRepository>();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


/*var host = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseKestrel()
  .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
  .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000", "http://192.168.0.243:5000")
  .UseIISIntegration()
  .UseStartup<Startup>()
  .Build(); */

var app = builder.Build();



// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseCors(builder => builder
       .AllowAnyHeader()
       .AllowAnyMethod()
       .AllowAnyOrigin()
    );
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

i have my xampp on
i try android emulation and real device, but localhost still cant connect, i also have minimal api one to connect to flutter but still the same, how to solve this?

Comment: Where is your app running? Where is your server running? Setup please.

Comment: Http protocol needs clear text traffic enabled in manifest file.

Comment: What do you consider to be localhost?

Comment: What does ip 127.0.0.1 stands for?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/62551334/17104517