# flutter http : Error: FormatException: http://10.0.2.2:8000

Tags: flutter, http

I try to connect flutter with django via flutters
`http`. Requests in `python` using `requests.post` work fine and I receive the authentification token.

I changed the standart adress `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`
according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372568/how-to-point-to-localhost8000-with-the-dart-http-package-in-flutter) to `http://10.0.2.2:8000` and
but receive the error

```dart
Error: FormatException: //10.0.2.2:8000
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49                       throw_
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 246:5                                  parse
dart-sdk/lib/core/uri.dart 1791:49                                                                 _makeHttpUri
dart-sdk/lib/core/uri.dart 1687:12                                                                 http
...
```

in

```dart
  final _tokenEndpoint = "/api-token-auth";
  var uri        = Uri.http(_base, _tokenEndpoint);
  final response = await http.post(uri,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'username': username,
        'password': password
      }));
```