# Glide failed to load resource

Tags: android, android-glide

I have problem when want to load image from server using `glide`

**this is my code**

```
Glide.with(ImagePreviewActivity.this).load(path).into(img);
```

**and this is the logcat :**

```
W/Glide: Load failed for 
http://localhost/AndroidFileUpload/file/IMG_20171128_153602.JPEG with size 
[720x1120]
                                                    class 
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
                                                      Cause (1 of 1): class 
com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class 
java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
                                                        Cause (1 of 1): 
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
                                                          Cause (1 of 1): 
class java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 
(port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

How to fix this problem ? Any suggestion would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: what is **path** and url is of localhost which can not accessibe

Comment: it seems like your image url is of localhost which can not accessibe from device.

Comment: so how to make it accessible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this line from your log

> class java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to
> localhost/127.0.0.1

That means your image path is on your localhost. If you run on emulator, localhost for your app is emulator. To access desktop, use special IP 10.0.2.2. If you run on device, localhost will be device - connect to desktop via local network IP.

That might create an issue. So, glide failed to load image.

Comment: so how to make it accessible from device ?

Comment: Make proper url using ip.

Comment: If you are accessing from emulator, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9515414/3364266

Comment: ooo thank you so much. i solve my problem by using ip instead localhost

Comment: Great. You can accept/upvote my answer so it will help others also.

Answer (score 1):

```
 - Glide.with(context)
                       .load(Zonelist.get(position)
                               .getZone_picture_url_3x()).apply(options).listener(new
   RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                       new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                           @Override
                           public void run() {
                               Glide.with(context)
                                       .load(Zonelist.get(position)
                                               .getZone_picture_url_3x())
                                       .into(imageView);
                           }

                       });
                       return false;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean
   isFirstResource) {
                       return false;
                   }
               }).into(imageView);
           }
```

Comment: this is not the exact way but helpful in case of failure :)