# Receiving data from localhost throws 'Connection Refused Error'

Tags: sockets, http, dart, flutter

I'm running a flutter app and trying to receive a json from localhost using:

```
Future<String> getJson() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull("http://localhost:3000/get"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    );
```

Whenever I run the app, I get an unhandled exception:

```
SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = 127.0.0.1, port = 48134
```

The port 48134 is open. Now, I thought of maybe changing my listening port to the port above. Doing that, switches the port in the error to some other random port and giving the same error. 
I don't understand why it's even looking for that port. It's not written anywhere. 
Anyone has any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are aware that `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` in Flutter is your emulator or phone, not your development machine?

Comment: I am definitely not. So what do I do if I have two projects on localhost with different ports and I want to access one from the other?

Comment: Got it. You can access the machine's localhost using `10.0.2.2`. Was not aware of what you said. Thank you :)

Comment: Didn't know about `10.0.2.2.` :D Glad to hear you figured it out.

Comment: All credit goes to: 
[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator)

Comment: Didn't know about the 10.0.2.2 either.