# Get JSON from URL function - NativeScript

Tags: json, nativescript

How to write the http module function to read data from local json file? I am now using this to read the data. I want the function to read the data from this url - http://localhost:8000/app/source.json

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var source = require("./source.json");
var properties = require("./properties.json");

function HomeViewModel() {
 var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable();

 viewModel.set("categoricalSource", source.categoricalSource);
 viewModel.set("categoryProperty", properties.categoryProperty);
 viewModel.set("valueProperty", properties.valueProperty);
 return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access localhost from the Android emulator, refer to [Accessing localhost:port from Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760585/accessing-localhostport-from-android-emulator)

In short - `http://10.0.2.2:<hostport>` replaces `localhost:<hostport>`

Refer to the [NativeScript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http) on `http` for making http requests. To access http://localhost:8000/app/source.json yours should look like so:

```
http.getJSON("http://10.0.2.2:8000/source.json").then(function (r) {
    //// Argument (r) is JSON!
}, function (e) {
    //// Argument (e) is Error!
    //console.log(e);
});
```

And finally, if you need to read a JSON from the application directory, a `require` should suffice.

Comment: Alright! So is this how you write it - viewModel.set("categoricalSource", source.categoricalSource); -  in the space where it says //Argument (r) is JSON!